# javascript - reorder a list without creating new list according to another list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a HTML list on a page with several items, each of which contain not just text but also input and tables. I also have a list for order like [3,1,2,0].

Is it possible to reorder the HTML list on the page according to the order list without creating a new list i.e. only the re-ordered list but not the original list shows up on the page?

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');

const order = [3,1,2,0];
```

```html
<ul>
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>item3</li>
<li>item4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what is `only one list on the page`?

Comment: If you don't create a new list you have overwrite the existing one.

Comment: There are a few sort algortims https://medium.com/@rajat_m/implement-5-sorting-algorithms-using-javascript-63c5a917e811

Comment: @appleapple I only want the re-ordered list (not the original) to show up on my page. sorry for confusion!

Comment: @AbrarHossain yes it is okay overwrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use Array [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) or [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) your array of indexes into a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)
- Finally, [.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) the iterable to the same parent UL element.

```js
const orderList = [3, 1, 2, 0];

const ul = document.querySelector('#list');
const li = ul.querySelectorAll('li'); 
ul.append(...orderList.map(i => li[i]));
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Using [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) seems slightly slower than the above method using Array destructuring using the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) as per [**this benchmark test**](https://jsfiddle.net/3m4fk5dy/1/)

```js
const liReordered = orderList.reduce((DF, i) => (DF.append(li[i]), DF), new DocumentFragment());
ul.append(liReordered);
```

By doing so **any event that's already assigned to that LI elements is preserved**, therefore not lost by reinserting them into the DOM (like it would be the case by using `innerHTML` or `insertAdjacentHTML` etc)

```js
const orderList = [3, 1, 2, 0];

const ul = document.querySelector('#list');
const li = ul.querySelectorAll('li'); 

li.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("Events are preserved!");
}));

ul.append(...orderList.map(i => li[i]));
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>0 CLICK ME</li>
  <li>1 CLICK ME</li>
  <li>2 CLICK ME</li>
  <li>3 CLICK ME</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: any reason use `DocumentFragment` here? doesn't have any benefit afaict.

Comment: @appleapple Does the last paragraph explains your question?

Comment: isn't it also preserved if you simply move the nodes?

Comment: I think it can also be written as `ul.append(...orderList.map(i=>li[i]));`

Comment: @appleapple sure you can do it like that. But I still think DocumentFragment should be the right toy for that purpose (If I recall well from performance tests).

Comment: per https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-append and https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#converting-nodes-into-a-node , it seems like it use `DocumentFragment` internally.

Comment: I'm no language-lawyer, so I'm not really sure.

Comment: anyway I doubt browser would not optimize this even if standard don't say anything.

Comment: @appleapple thank you for your valuable insight - after doing again (after quite some time) some some tests on that matter - seems that destructuring and appending is a little bit faster: - Although chrome seems to crash if destructuring is used instead of DF on a large dataset. Might be worth seeing: https://jsfiddle.net/3m4fk5dy/1/

Comment: thanks for the test :) I got same result from that fiddle (destructuring is slightly faster)